# Variable not printing on iteration

Tags: c++11

I'm writing a C++ CSV class for a personal project, but have stumbled on a weird error.  In my test program I have the code:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
    std::cout << i << ": ";
    std::vector<std::string> results = test.get_row();
    for( auto it = results.begin(); it != results.end(); ++it ) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And get the results:

```
 : row0 row1 row2
 : blah0 blah1 blah2
2: blah3 blah4 blah5
```

But I should be getting:

```
0: row0 row1 row2
1: blah0 blah1 blah2
2: blah3 blah4 blah5
```

Any ideas as to why I'm not getting the `i` value on the first two runs?

Note: I'm using g++ 4.4.7

Comment: Please consider upgrading the compiler (although it has nothing to do with the issue). Are you on Windows? Because I half-expect you to have windows "CRLF" line ends in the input.

Comment: @sehe: I'm compiling on CentOS.  I haven't upgraded yet, although have been meaning to get to it.

Comment: If `c++11` you can use `for( auto i : results ) { ... foo... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah. I think I see it:

You appear to have forgotten to strip the newlines from the input.

This would resulting in the last column having a trailing '\r', and since you *always* add a ' ', this space will overwrite the originally printed `i`.

Strip the newline character from the input before splitting columns values :)

Comment: That solved the issue.  I stripped the '\r' character from my get_rows function.  I will accept as soon as the system allows me.

Comment: Re. "I'm compiling on CentOS": That would indeed explain it: if you have Windows-style textfiles, CentOS will only strip UNIX line ends (`\n`) leaving the 'extra' `\r` in the last column value. `\r` is _actually_ carriage return. As in: return carriage (of typewriter) to the left margin. Perfect explanation.