# C++ First two elements not printing properly when using iterator

Tags: c++

I have looked for this and found something here: [Variable not printing on iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624060/variable-not-printing-on-iteration) but I'm not sure if that necessarily applies.

What I have going on is my program correctly prints all values when I call it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SampleVec.Matchups().size(); ++i){
    std::cout << SampleVec.Matchups()[i] << std::endl;
}
```

or when I call it like this:

```
std::vector<int> temp;
temp = SampleVec.Matchups();
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = temp.begin(); iter != temp.end(); iter++){
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

but when I write it like this

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = SampleVec.Matchups().begin(); iter != SampleVec.Matchups().end(); iter++){
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

the first two values show up as a 0 and the rest print correctly.  In the link I posted they talk about stripping newlines from the input, but I don't know if that applies here or even how to do that.  I can post full code if needed to run and see the functionality in action.

Comment: dont post full code. Please read about [mcve] and provide one.

Comment: What is the signature for Matchups()?

Comment: @Niall std::vector<int> Matchups() const;

Comment: Ok. The posted answer covers this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = SampleVec.Matchups().begin(); iter != SampleVec.Matchups().end(); iter++){
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

`begin()` returns the iterator of the beginning of a temporary `std::vector` returned by `Matchups()`. At the moment of using `iter` it's a dangling iterator because the temporary has been destroyed and thus you have Undefined Behaviour.

You have to store the result before trying to access it through an iterator like you do in example 2.

Comment: Thanks, @Gill.  I understand what you mean.  Just wondering if there's a place where I could read more about what's causing this.  Typing "dangling iterator" in google returns some scary pictures.

Comment: @Jeff `begin()` returns an iterator, which is basically just a pointer with some member functions to the start of the vector. Because you chain your calls `Matchups().begin()` the value returned by `Matchups()` is a temporary that's destroyed after the `begin()` call. So the `begin()` call is done, the temporary is destroyed, and now you're left with a pointer (iterator) to a place of memory (the start of the vector) that is deleted. Trying to dereference that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If I could up-vote more than once I would.  Thanks very much, you've been extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: just thinking about it now, if the location the iterator was pointing to vanishes then why does it print correct values after printing 0 for only the first two?

Comment: @Jeff because it's undefined behaviour, anything can happen. Don't try to make sense out of something thats undefined.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again